# How to add click event on hotspot or load event of image in mpetroff/pannellum plugin

Tags: javascript, html, pannellum

Can anyone suggest me with a short example that how to bind click event on hotspot and image load event. 
I tried using "clickHandlerFunc" attribute but unable to add click handler on hotspot or image. 
Please suggest me, with any basic click event using "mpetroff/pannellum" panorma. 
My requirement is to fetch image data on load of image or on click of hotspot.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One suggestion would be to use the `scenechange` and `load` API events exposed by Pannellum (https://pannellum.org/documentation/reference/#api-events).  I think it would indirectly achieve what you are looking for since they trigger every time a new scene is loaded.

`scenechange` triggers when a scene change is triggered (eg by clicking on a scene hotspot).  `load` triggers when a scene has fully loaded (ie all the images have loaded).

Here is an example of how this would look.

```
  viewer = pannellum.viewer('panorama', ﻿{ 
   // Insert your pannellum config here
   });

  viewer.on('scenechange', function (){
   // Insert handler here
  });
```